# Iterate collection of collections using Java Stream?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

How can I refactor this code using Java 8 Stream API?

```
for (Role role: user.getRoles()) {
    for (Privilege privilege: role.getPrivileges()) {
        System.out.println(privilege.getName());
    }
}
```

Tried this way:

```
user.getRoles().stream()
               .map(role -> role.getPrivileges())
               .forEach(privelege -> System.out.println(privelege.getName()));
```

Comment: What have you already tried to code?

Comment: In this case, a stream-less `user.getRoles().forEach(role -> role.getPrivileges().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName()));` would do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine [`.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and [`.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
user.getRoles()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(role -> role.getPrivileges().stream())
    .map(Privilege::getName)
    .forEach(System.out::println)
```